# Is it possible to use an enum in place of another if its a subset?

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say we have two enum lists: A and B. Enum A is a list of clothes, and B is a subset of A.

Example

```
enum A //Clothes
{
    hats,
    pants,
    shirts,
    gloves,
    jacket,
    boots,
    skirt,
    suit,
    sweater,
    hoodie,
    beanie,
    ...
}

enum B //subset of A, contains only stuff you can put on your head
{
    hats = A.hats,
    beanie = A.beanie,
    ...
}
```

Can I use enum B in place of A?

For example, in a dictionary `Dictionary<A, T> foo`, how can I do: `foo[B.hats]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast between enums.

```cs
foo[(A)B.hats]
```